# Send Mail using PHP to @me addresses

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm actually using the PHP code below to send a mail at my "@me" address:

```
<?php
$to      = 'myName@me.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It works fine with Gmail but I'm not receiving any mail when trying to use with my iCloud mail address...any idea of how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are  sending small amount of mails, you should use **[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)**
as it will give you the flexibility to send mails to any service with any configurations needed, easy attachment and everything you may need.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Hi, I just need to send a mail once in a while for a simple "password forgotten" reminder ;)

Comment: Which mail server are you using, in mail, it uses the local mail server of your computer, in XAMP or WAMP etc. So Gmail may be accepting g it but marked fraud by iCloud. as Mail have designated whitelist servers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your server mail configuration. Try using libraries like PHPMailer to send mails to anywhere. Also it needs to enable IMAP to get this mail sending to work.
http://phpmailer.worxware.com